# What is wrong with my bash script?

Tags: bash

What I have to to is edit a script given to me that will check if the user has write permission for a file named journal-file in the user's home directory. The script should take appropriate actions if journal-file exists and the user does not have write permission to the file.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
    if [ -w $HOME/journal-file ]
        then
            file=$HOME/journal-file
            date >> file
            echo -n "Enter name of person or group: "
            read name
            echo "$name" >> $file
            echo >> $file
            cat >> $file
            echo "--------------------------------" >> $file
            echo >> $file
            exit 1
        else
            echo "You do not have write permission."
            exit 1
    fi
```

When I run the script it prompt me to input the name of the person/group, but after I press enter nothing happens. It just sits there allowing me to continue inputting stuff and doesn't continue past that part. Why is it doing this?

Comment: you really shouldn't just submit code and ask what is wrong with it

Answer (score 3):

The  statement:

```
cat >>$file
```

will read from standard input and write to the file. That means it will wait until you indicate end of file with something like CTRL-D. It's really no different from just typing `cat` at a command line and seeing that nothing happens until you enter something and it waits until you indicate end of file.

If you're trying to append another file to the output file, you need to specify its name, such as `cat $HOME/myfile.txt >>$file`.

If you're trying to get a blank line in there, use `echo` rather than `cat`, such as `echo >>$file`.

You also have a couple of other problems, the first being:

```
date >> file
```

since that will try to create a file called `file` (in your working directory). Use `$file` instead.

The second is the exit code of `1` in the case where what you're trying to do has succeeded.  That may not be a problem now but someone using this at a later date may wonder why it seems to indicate failure always.

To be honest, I'm not really a big fan of the `if ... then return else ...` construct. I prefer fail-fast with less indentation and better grouping of output redirection, such as:

```
file=${HOME}/journal-file
if [[ ! -w ${file} ]] ; then
    echo "You do not have write permission."
    exit 1
fi

echo -n "Enter name of person or group: "
read name
(
    date
    echo "$name"
    echo
    echo "--------------------------------"
    echo
) >>${file}
```

I believe that's far more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

It's this line

```
cat >> $file
```

`cat` is  concatenating input from standard input (ie whatever you type) to `$file`

Answer (score 1):

I think the part

`cat >> $file`

copies everything from stdin to the file.  Maybe if you hid Ctrl+D (end of file) the script can continue.

Answer (score 0):

1) You better check first whether the file exists or not:

```
[[ -e $HOME/journal-file ]] || \
    { echo "$HOME/journal-file does not exist"; exit 1 }
```

2) You gotta change "cat >> $file" for whatever you want to do with the file. This is the command that is blocking the execution of the script.